# Need an "at" Command Timestamp That Runs Command Monthly at Given Day

Tags: bash, command-line, date, job-control, at

Need an `at` command timestamp that run some command at given day monthly, like for example, every day 15, as would follow:

`$ at every 15 day`

So that on every day 15, it would run some command.

How would I set it?

Comment: I'd use `cron` for that.

Comment: But how I would do that??

Comment: It looks you work on some Unix-like systems so type `man crontab`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, `cron` is the right tool to do so. `at` is used to run a command at a specified time and date but only once.

Just add this line to `/etc/crontab`:

```
0  7  15  *   *   youruser  /path/to/somecommand
```

This runs the specified command at 7:00 AM every 15th of the month.

For more information, see the manpages:

```
man cron
man crontab
```

Comment: A personal crontab might be more appropriate if `youruser` is a “real” user.

Comment: see also `man 5 crontab` which documents the file format of crontab files.  `man crontab` only documents the `crontab` command.